# gmaps4rails 1.4.7 dosen't show map in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production, gmaps4rails

Is gmaps4rails version 1.4.7 working in production for anyone. I have a app where the only thing I changed was going from 1.4.5 to 1.4.7. and all of a sudden the maps maps are blank, controls are there but no map image. I use rails 3.2.1 and the asset pipeline is enabled.

Are there any changes I need to do to go from 1.4.5 to 1.4.7?

Comment: I'm really sorry to read that. Re-reading my code, I made one mistake and just released 1.4.8. Please tell me if this fixes. Thanks

Comment: Rutger, I suggest you post something like `bug found with 1.4.7; solution is to upgrade to 1.4.8` and take credit for finding the issue apneadiving corrected

Comment: will do on next production update